# cannot find the Tag library for HDIV 2.1.11

Tags: hdiv

I am trying to integrate HDIV 2.1.11 i my application. Everything looks good except that I cannot find the taglib files. Where can I download the tag library definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which web framework are you using?
If you are using Spring MVC 3.1 (or higher) or Grails, there is not HDIV's tags so there is not any taglib, HDIV is integrated within web framework tags.